# Nest object type destructuring

Tags: typescript, graphql, relay

How can I get the type definition from a nested object?

In this example I get a list of entities(products) how can I access the type definition for the entity(node).

This is compiled using `relay-compiler`

```
export type ProductAutoSuggestQueryResponse = {
     node: {
         products?: {
             edges: ReadonlyArray<{
                 node: {
                     name: string;
                     id: string;
                     currencies: ReadonlyArray<string> | null;
                };
            } | null> | null;
        } | undefined;
    } | null;
};
```

I have tried using `Pick<>` but it seem to get very complex and the array is causing me issue.

Comment: You have two properties named `node`, what type are you trying to get out?  [Is this what you want?](https://tsplay.dev/Wk57JN).  How generalizable do you need this to be?  Any other use cases or edge cases we need to be concerned with?

Comment: You can write a recursive type function to perform a "non-nullable deep index" like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyOAKN), if that's what you want.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz in this instance I am trying to get the 2nd node but I have different queries so the node could be at different depths. The 2nd comment you posted looks great. I assume I have to put `number` in the path when I get to an array?

Comment: Yeah, to get the element type of an array, you index into the array with an index of type `number`; it's just like indexing into an object to get the property (since arrays are just objects).  I will write up an answer explaining this if it all meets your needs.  (Could be an hour or two from now, btw)

Comment: Yeah that is totally what I was looking for! No rush. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually you want to take `ProductAutoSuggestQueryResponse` and [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) deeply.  Let's imagine that this type had been:

```
type ProductAutoSuggestQueryResponse = {
    node: {
        products: {
            edges: readonly {
                node: {
                    name: string;
                    id: string;
                    currencies: readonly string[];
                };
            }[];
        };
    };
}
```

Given a value `v` of the modified version of `ProductAutoSuggstQueryResponse`, you could get a value of the desired node type by reading, say, `v.node.products.edges[0].node`.  More generally, you could get such a value by reading `v[p][q][r][i][s]` when `p` is of type `'node'` and `q` is of type `'products'` and `r` is of type `'edges'` and `i` is of type `number` and `s` is of type `'node'`. Such indexing can be done at the type level with indexed access types:

```
type NodeType =
  ProductAutoSuggestQueryResponse['node']['products']['edges'][number]['node'];
/* type NodeType = {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    currencies: readonly string[];
} */
```

Which is what you want.

---

So that's great.  Unfortunately your `ProductAutoSuggestQueryResponse` type is not exactly what I wrote above.  At various levels through the object structure, there are [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) or otherwise `null`able properties, meaning that they can include `undefined` or `null`.  Instead of `{a: string}`, you've got `{a: string} | undefined` or `{a: string} | null` or `{a: string} | undefined | null`.  You can't safely index into something which might be `undefined` or `null`, so the compiler won't let you use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) directly.

What you *can* do is use [the `NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) to turn something like `{a: string} | undefined | null` into `{a: string}` before you index into it.  This can be done manually, but it's annoying:

```
type NodeTypeManual = NonNullable<
    NonNullable<
        NonNullable<
            NonNullable<
                ProductAutoSuggestQueryResponse['node']
            >['products']
        >['edges']
    >[number]
>['node']

/* type NodeTypeManual = {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    currencies: ReadonlyArray<string> | null;
} */
```

If you find that you're going to do this often, you can write a recursive [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that operates on a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of indices:

```
type NonNullableDeepIndex<T, KT extends PropertyKey[]> =
    KT extends [infer KF, ...infer KR] ? (
        KF extends keyof NonNullable<T> ? (
            NonNullableDeepIndex<NonNullable<T>[KF], Extract<KR, PropertyKey[]>>
        ) : never
    ) : NonNullable<T>;
```

The type function `NonNullableDeepIndex` takes a type `T` and a tuple of keys `KT`.  If the tuple of keys is empty, we just return `NonNullable<T>`.  Otherwise we grab the first key `KF` and index into `NonNullable<T>` with `KF`, and take the new type and the rest of the key tuple `KR`, and recursively evaluate `NonNullableDeepIndex`.

Then we can express `NodeType` a little less repetitively as:

```
type NodeType = NonNullableDeepIndex<
    ProductAutoSuggestQueryResponse,
    ["node", "products", "edges", number, "node"]
>;
/* type NodeType = {
    name: string;
    id: string;
    currencies: ReadonlyArray<string> | null;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKUIBMCuBjGAQRxggGUcBzS4AZxgEUdgpEAlOyAO1tQF44AbwCwAKDgS4XbMABcQsZKVwwmXAVoB+eSPHL9wLDVryOAQywQuAG0SEoUM4gA8u-e8nSschXo-+pMwBbH3ooAEsuSgBuRQD-cKx5MMiYuPj3PBwHYC48cLpTYAsrW3tHFxSogD44AB8pHGtrWL8MuABfVoyO+sbm2oauJpb05V6GnC5vADNIw27JCf7R0S6xMS5gzjM8VAB1AAszGABJGdOYAAkLADkIW5GzACNrYAB5KHewGHCrM2sGAgKFgBVovjGSBQcAAIsBgGB7lxHs0Xm9nAAVWp8MZKJEo6xo4CY2qgGC5LDgyIzFhwACqcE0QjgAG0ANJwSJwADWwEQEBm9IAugBabSw+GIqwEonOOnsoW1XryLjAABuLFakOQqDhCPxT1ewCB6iIJHIVGMjGYrA4tG4vDgAj1UuRhvRJvwZtIFGodGtLHYnCsvGqYwA9AAqBA6iX66Xu41qL3EH2W-1MQN2h38XweLw+NzxVTYL0mPPtCSGYzyKDFSw2RAVytKAs6XEt1vbZIwCJRRad-SJHt9tJtQeSLI5PJg2v10pNqqUFlCgeD9bj+IdFdrjwbvdr3qR8MbNpQ1D3bwY2M4zcSF0G1FGz0EVMWv30TO24M8YAsgDkBb-kKAElqatDAQB1Z0JBwxBM8LAgYBMjAWuUYxtCl7ANe0ICEW+hbCEI6pLukjDnAS6kRIU51jOhRwHWJSNhRvapDuYxHieohiB0p6ETsexwAAsmYwwArYHAoCcj6EkapzTKAqQQmesZYThuYybKHYSJpRrONpyi6eiBkeEZxImfEL7eu+VpfkG9ohn+yHeMBFn6NUoHJhorl3soHn-tBEFCgZHlwQhUDBW0-lAZFEbRuecBqTezbKPxxH9gZ5GUQZNG5Pk9HmA2ZQOE4zhLoMKyHnAx6nrx3H1QlZkuvJ3ggJiAA0cBshicBkhS4JAiCSBsnyK7YmM3W9SA5LTOCLLUrSbIAGKdQAdOtC1QF1bBCoycAABQGctU0zZSPJ8gKiUJk+6JYnth2+Xi12yW8zUKW1ZkkuyS1Cp1ACi02OAQzhsmwnWDSww2jYqYa+QAlHAKrqiwYwI-In1YlqoiNTI6lOldbo3cAb2tfpbRWW+vq2Ta9k5u1YwsgARAWjOdYzYFlqzcCM4FXNhSwbMs5F1StOhONXsl+GBERLGjmuWWsRlbS5XR5aFQu5SleVfTDM0rScUAA)